# How to change a sub layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbie in android, but I want to change the contents of a layout, that is inside another layout, due to clicks on buttons.

```
-----------------------------
| Button |  Button | Button |
-----------------------------
|                           |
|  Layout that changes      |
|        dynamically        |
|                           |
|                           |
------------------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

get a reference to the changing layout:

```
LinearLayout changingLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.changing_layout);
```

then get its layout parameters:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)changingLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

then change any paramter you wish, for example:

```
lp.setMargins(newLeft,newTop,newRight,newBottom);
```

and finally:

```
changingLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

If you wish to change the visible views this layout contains, i would suggest:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```